# Google Charts DataTable no longer working after upgrades in .NET Core and Angular version

Tags: angular, google-visualization

I have been upgrading my build environment and have broken my Google DataTable code.  Changes from the working version to the broken version include

- upgrading .NET Core from 2.1 to 3.1,
- upgrading from Angular 5 to 8.2,
- placing the chart code in a feature module.

The last item is highly suspect, but other chart code in the module appears to be working.  So anyway, the relevant code that was working perfectly before follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
selector: 'google-chart',
templateUrl: './google-chart.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./google-chart.component.css']
})
export class GoogleChartComponent implements OnInit {

public chartData: any;
public dataTable: any;

public options = {
    title: 'Google Line Chart Example',
    width: 600,
    height: 370
};

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
}

ngOnInit() {

google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

this.http.get('api/binomialresults/getgooglechartdata') 
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.chartData = response;
            this.dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(this.chartData);
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawChart.bind(this));
        });
}
private drawChart(this: any) {

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));

    chart.draw(this.dataTable, this.options);
}

}
```

Here is the module definition:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { GoogleChartComponent } from './google-chart.component';
import { GoogleTestChartComponent } from './google-test-chart.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    GoogleChartComponent,
    GoogleTestChartComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    GoogleChartComponent,
    GoogleTestChartComponent
  ],
  providers: [
  ],

})
export class GoogleChartsModule { }
```

And finally, here is the error, captured from the Chrome console:
[image]

There are no errors apparent in the visual studio console and the content of this.chartData can be seen as good in the debugger.  The error message is thrown on setting the value for this.dataTable.  I have researched the "Cannot read property of 'DataTable' of undefined" error and the usual answers involve failure to load the google charts environment.  That is not the case here, or at least I am using the load statement that works elsewhere.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` needs to finish before trying to use `google.visualization` namespace. can you create the data table inside `drawChart`?

Comment: I just tried that and did not manage to make it work.  Maybe I didn't get it right.  I have moved ahead with my chart library by providing a dummy dataTable in a class that implements OnChanges and gets its data through input from the using component. The dummy datatable is overwritten as soon as the async retrieval finishes - too quick to see.  Works but not very satisfying.

Comment: if you want to edit the question with the latest code, I'll take a look...

Comment: I will try to get something up soon.  My library has grown a bit so it will take some editing to get something down to size for an example.  I may post as an answer since it is now working.  Am using BehaviorSubjects in the data service to insure at least some default data is always available to the charting environment.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what has changed in moving to the newer environment but I have something that seems to be working so I thought I would share.  The key problem appears to be that Google Charts are not going to wait for async data loading.  I have tried several ways to beat this but have settled on the following as a basis for a charting library.  In my case a basic requirement is to update the charts any time a user submits a new calculation request and this makes things a little more complicated but perhaps it will help someone else who might be facing similar issues.  And perhaps some critical review will result in improvements.  Note that what follows is extracted from my charting library, and I am leaving out some pieces (like model definitions) that would make a complete example.

First, the most important part, the data service for components that will be using the chart data:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

import { PoissonResult } from '../models/poisson-result.model';

//  Summary:
//  Retrieve a PoissonResult object from the server.
//

// Url to the API controller class.
const urlBase = `api/poissonresults`;

@Injectable()
export class PoissonResultService {

  // Private BehaviorSubject source to be pushed as poissonResult observable.
  private poissonResultSource: any;

  // Public result data.
  public poissonResult : any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
    // Initialize the chart data so that it will always be defined
    // for any google charts that may be using it.  Google Charts won't wait
    // for async loading.  Data will update as soon as any calculations are
    // performed.
    var initialResult = new PoissonResult();
    initialResult.output = "Ready";
    initialResult.chartData = {
      cols: [
        { id: 'X', label: 'X', type: 'number' },
        { id: 'Prior', label: 'Prior', type: 'number' },
        { id: 'Posterior', label: 'Posterior', type: 'number' }
      ],
      rows: [
        { c: [{ v: 0.0 }, { v: 0.0 }, { v: 0.0 }] },
        { c: [{ v: 1.0 }, { v: 0.0 }, { v: 0.0 }] }
      ]
    };

    this.poissonResultSource = new BehaviorSubject<PoissonResult>(initialResult);
    this.poissonResult = this.poissonResultSource.asObservable();
  }

  getPoissonResult(inputValues: any) {
     // Retrieve new results and push the updated values. 
    const url = `/getpoissonresult/${inputValues.failureCount}/${inputValues.timePeriod}/${inputValues.priorType}`;
    this.http.get<PoissonResult>(urlBase + url)
      .subscribe(result => this.poissonResultSource.next(result));
  }

}
```

The key item here is the initialResult.chartData.  This initializes the chart data for any chart component using the service, eliminating the "DataTable undefined" error.

Now for a component that uses the the data service. This is largely based on a blog posting, http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/10/12/using-google-charts-in-angular-4-project-part-2/ , that I found helpful:

```
<div>
  <line-chart [data]="poissonResult.chartData"
              [config]="config"
              [elementId]="elementId">
  </line-chart>
</div>
```

and the component that uses the template:

```
export class InitiatingEventsComponent implements OnInit {

  // Instance variables not set via dependency injection
  private inputForm: FormGroup;
  private poissonResult: PoissonResult;

  // Google chart set up.  Chart data is provided by poissonResult.chartData.
  public config: LineChartConfig;
  public elementId: string;

  // Constructor provides the data service and form builder.
  constructor(
    private dataService: PoissonResultService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // The input form setup
    this.inputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'priorType': [0],
      'failureCount': [0],
      'timePeriod': [0]
    });

    // Chart configuration
    this.config = new LineChartConfig('Prior and Posterior Likelihood Functions', '\u03BB');
    this.elementId = 'lineChart';

    // Initial results before any calculations
    this.dataService.poissonResult.subscribe(result => this.poissonResult = result);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // Ask the data service to retrieve results based on user input.
    this.dataService.getPoissonResult(this.inputForm.value);   
  }

}
```

The rest of the chart component code follows very closely to the blog posting referenced above.  I have modified it slightly to fit my application better, so I am showing the modified portions:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

import { LineChartService } from '../services/line-chart.service';
import { LineChartConfig } from '../models/line-chart.config';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnChanges {

    @Input() data: any; 
    @Input() config: LineChartConfig;
    @Input() elementId: string;

  constructor(
    private lineChartService: LineChartService) {   
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: { [propKey: string]: SimpleChange }): void {    
        this.lineChartService.BuildLineChart(this.elementId, this.data, this.config);
  }

}
```

Note that implementing OnChanges is important to keeping current with updated chart data.  The LineChartService:

```
//
//  References:
//  1. http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/10/12/using-google-charts-in-angular-4-project-part-2/
//
//  To use insert symbols in text areas use unicode:  \uXXXX
//  https://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561380-xhtml-characters-list.aspx?type=script&category=greek-coptic
//
import { GoogleChartsBaseService } from './google-charts.base.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LineChartConfig } from './../models/line-chart.config';

declare var google: any;

@Injectable()
export class LineChartService extends GoogleChartsBaseService {

  constructor(
  ) {
    super();
  }

  public BuildLineChart(elementId: string, data: any, config: LineChartConfig): void {    
    var chartFunc = () => { return new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(elementId)); };
    var options = {
      title: config.title,
      width: 600,
      height: 370,
      chartArea: { left: 40, top: 30 },
      curveType: 'none',
      hAxis: {
        title: config.hAxisTitle + '\n\n\n\n',
        textStyle: {
          //color: '#01579b',
          //fontSize: 20,
          fontName: 'Arial',
          bold: false,
          italic: false
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
          //color: '#01579b',
          //fontSize: 16,
          fontName: 'Arial',
          bold: false,
          italic: false
        }
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Likelihood',
        textStyle: {
          //color: '#1a237e',
          //fontSize: 24,
          bold: false,
          italic: false
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
          //color: '#1a237e',
          //fontSize: 24,
          bold: false,
          italic: false
        }
      },
    };

    this.buildChart(data, chartFunc, options);
  }
}
```

And finally, the base class:

```
//  References:
//
//  1.  http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/10/12/using-google-charts-in-angular-4-project-part-2/
//

declare var google: any;

export class GoogleChartsBaseService {
  constructor() {
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
  }

  protected buildChart(data: any, chartFunc: any, options: any): void {
    var func = (chartFunc, options) => {
      var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
      chartFunc().draw(datatable, options);
    };
    var callback = () => func(chartFunc, options);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(callback);
  }

}
```

If anyone wants the missing pieces, I can update this, but it is already fairly lengthy.